# pass value from json object from view to variable in model

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I am new to MVC and i am trying to pass value from json object from view to model variable. how can i do that.

### model

```
public guid SID{ get; set; }
```

### view

```
@model StudentSchoolActivity.ViewModels.ApplicationViewModel


 success: function(result) {
                if (result == 1) {
                  Model.SID= result.SID;
 }
```

when i debug the code it says uncaught reference error for Model.SID= result.SID.

I need to store the value inside model so that i can use that value on controller.

Comment: Presumably your model is bound to controls in the view. I'm not ware of how to set the model directly like you have suggested. I'd simply set the bound controls property to the new value returned. $("#SID").val(result.SID)

Comment: Your model exists only on the server, not in the browser. You cannot mix server side and client side code like that.

Answer (score 1):

Rohil Patel , we can easily do this by using the jquery ajax, below is the example :

**View Code:**

```
$("#AnybuttonId").click(function () {
    var studentdata = {
        Sid: $("#txtsid").val(),
        studentname: $("#txtsname").val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Home/savestudent",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(studentdata),
        success: function (result) {

           //some code
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //some code
        }
    }); 
});
```

**Controller code:**

```
[HttpPost]

    public ActionResult savestudent(Student studentdata)
    {

       //action logic like save will be here


}
```

Hope it was easily understandable and  helpful,kindly let me know your thoughts or feedbacks

Thanks

Karthik

Comment: I am not using any textbox value, I  want to assign that value from json reult to mdoel variable. @Karthik

Comment: ok then send the jsonresult from the controller instead of actionresult, and then assign the value  to the model in the success function. you can see the example here:https://shashankshetty.wordpress.com/2009/03/04/using-jsonresult-with-jquery-in-aspnet-mvc/ thanks karthik

Answer (score 0):

To use the value in the controller, you have to send it back as part of a request. The code you have shown is invalid because `Model.SID` is a server side construct (Razor), but the JS code (`result.SID`) runs on the client.

If you use a POST request, you can bind the value to a hidden input. (I use jQuery to manipulate the DOM in this example):

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SID)

/* ... */
success: function(result) {
    if (result == 1) {
        $('#SID').val(result.SID);
    }
}
```

If you use a GET request, you can format the value into the matching URL parameter.

```
var link = '@Url.Action("Details", "MyController", new { sid = "__0__" })';
if (result == 1) {
    link = link.replace('__0__', result.SID);
}
```